# AWS API Gateway not passing headers

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-api-gateway

I'm using AWS API Gateway and passing the requests as HTTP Proxy to my nginx/php-fpm server.

on my server i print all the headers that arrived from the HTTP POST request.
on AWS:

1. added "Location" header under "Method Request" HTTP Request Headers
2. mapped "Location" header under "Integration Request" HTTP Headers:

> Name: Location
>
> Mapped from: method.request.header.Location

i'm using postman to send the POST request with additional headers but the header is not forwarded...any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Can you see in the logs for the request (either in the console on the 'Test' page, or in CloudWatch Logs on the deployed API) if the headers are being sent to the endpoint? There should be verbose logs in the 'Test' page that tell you exactly what is being sent to/from the endpoint.

And is it all headers for you or just 'Location'?